# How to make shell script restart Java if any thread crashes?

Tags: bash, java

I have a multi threaded Java program.

Ideally it should run once and successfully terminate.

Unfortunately, sometimes one of the threads crashes, such as by throwing
`DivisionByZeroException`.

Since the program is useless unless all threads are running, I would like to completely restart JVM (and the program) whenever one of the threads is down.

**Question:**
how do I write a shell script which would do that?

The pseudo code for the shell script that I am looking is:

```
#bin/bash
while (true) {
   sudo java -jar MyProgram.jar
   if (MyProgram.terminatedWithoutExceptions) { // How to write this part?
       finish;
   } else {
       shutdown JVM;
   }
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off modifying your program to either 1) not have threads crash randomly or 2) gracefully handle thread exceptions with an [exception handler](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-). In any case this would be a question for [SO].

Comment: 1) Threads are not written by me. Making sure that EVERY thread has no bugs which can crash it is very tricky. Restarting the program is conceptually simpler.

2) Exception handler doesn't seem to work properly (or at least I haven't found a proper way for it to work). Even if it catches an exception raised by one thread, it does not **stop and restart** all threads. Stopping threads seems to be hard to do in Java. A simple instruction such as `Thread.interrupt()` doesn't seem to work as expected, unless I am missing something (am I)?

Comment: I'm willing to discuss a solution to your question(s) in a more appropriate environment, i. e. [SO].

Answer (score 3):

One of the more basic relationships between a program and the parent shell is the concept of an "exit code". This is a simple integer that —by convention— lets the shell know there was a problem.

Zero is "everything went fine", anything else is "omghoustonproblems". Again this is just a convention. Some things (eg `grep -q ...`) use the exit code to indicate if there was a match. Grep *ran* without error, but it's using the exit code to signal something else here.

Anyway, I assume if your Java app blows up to the point where it's segfaulting, or something else, it doesn't exit cleanly. So by extension the exit code it sends back to the parent shell is not zero. That makes it really easy to test:

```
while true; do
    sudo java -jar MyProgram.jar
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        // it exited cleanly, do something good
    else
        // it crashed out, do something else
    fi
done
```

If you want to exit the while-loop in one of those if clause-sides, insert a `break`.

Is running the Java program as root really a great idea? Who knows. I don't know who this outer script is being run as  so no judgement at this point but consider refactoring it out if you can.

---

The above is accurate but re-reading your question you might want to change how you pool your threads. It's been ~13 years since I did any threading work in Java and that was just academic but a number of things occur to me:

- Divide-by-zero problems are avoidable by validating input.
- They're also catchable. Don't let them crash the thread. Catch, log and move on.
- A thread runner that lets threads crash without starting a new one is a rubbish one. Find something more robust.

The best solution isn't going to be cleaning up when things go wrong, it's going to be stopping them getting that far in the first place. It can be done.

Comment: Extra +1 for the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: What if one thread crashed, but another is still running? Would the main Java tread of execution stop or still be running? Would the bash script ever reach `if` part and would `[$? -eq 0]` evaluate to false in that case?

Apart from that, thx for helpful post :-)

Comment: No the first bit is only going to help if the bit the shell launched crashes. You really need to look into how you're handling exceptions in and around your thread pool. This is all internal to Java, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0924/ for some more ideas.